# Matplotlib subplot2grid doesn't work properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, matplotlib, graph

I am trying to code a simple nuclear fission simulation and thus far I've got the simulation of the core itself working properly. Now what I am trying to do is to have a second graph near the simulation, that tells the user how much power is being outputted from the core.

With that being said, I am trying to use `subtplot2grid` but I can't seem to find the right fitting measurements for my program. I also add a patch of `plt.Rectangle` into the core simulation that I use as bounds to my core, I tried running the program with and without the patch and it seems like it is the problem. Even though, I would like that rectangle to stay, please help me find the right measurements and explain why are the dimensions different with and without the patch.

here's my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

BOUNDS = [-20,20,-20,20]

fig = plt.figure()

ax = plt.subplot2grid((3,2),(0,0), rowspan = 2, colspan = 2, aspect = 'equal', autoscale_on = False,
                          xlim = (-51.2,51.2), ylim = (-50.4,50.4))
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3,2),(2,1))

ax1.set_xlabel('Time')
ax1.set_ylabel('Jouls')

rect = plt.Rectangle(BOUNDS[::2], #Creates the frame of the board (black rectangle)
                 BOUNDS[1] - BOUNDS[0],
                 BOUNDS[3] - BOUNDS[2],
                 ec='black', lw=2, fc='none')


ax.add_patch(rect)
ax.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

If you will run the program, you will see this: 
[image]

Like I said before, I would like the power graph to be near the simulation, which will take up most of the figure, like so:

[image]

I would appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly you want to use an additional column and let the "core" plot span all 3 rows?

```
ax = plt.subplot2grid((3,3),(0,0), rowspan = 3, colspan = 2, aspect = 'equal',
                      autoscale_on = False, xlim = (-51.2,51.2), ylim = (-50.4,50.4))
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3),(1,2))
```

[image]

Comment: `ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3),(2,2))`  would fit his scope rather.

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for. I also changed the `BOUNDS` of the rectangle frame to fit it in better with the subplot and played around a bit with `subplots_adjust` to finalize how it looks. Thanks again!